# how to set a qplot to full width on a knitr output to microsoft word or html

Tags: html, r

I have a r script with a standard qplot:

```
fq <- qplot(x=date, y=count, data=foundationfinal,
      main = "foundation-related opportunities",
      xlab = "Timeline (by Date)",
      ylab="Count with offerings",
      facet = ~terms
fq <- fq +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90, hjust = 1)
fq <- fq + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="green")
```

it prints perfectly, but is narrow for the number of charts that appar in the lattice.  How do I tell qplot to plot the "full" width and standard height of a word document or html document when applying to knitr? in other words, how do I scale to full width?

Thanks.

Comment: you can control width with fig.width parameter in the knitr chunk header `\`\`\`{r fig.width=8, fig.height=8}`. Not sure how to make it full width automatically though.

Comment: You can set the default width at the beginning of the document so that it applies to all plots. In the first code chunk add the following statement (with whatever width you prefer): `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=8)`